# This item may not have a label readable by screen readers

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerlistview

I have a recommendation in play console after I tried to publish my app.

This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.

the xml code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="clickable_image7_meegat"
            android:src="@drawable/dhoalhulaifah">

        </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

the java adapter code:

```
  public Almashaaer_Adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from (context);
        View view=inflater.inflate (R.layout.single_item,parent,false);

        return new Almashaaer_Adapter.MyViewHolder(view,recyclerViewInterface);
    }
```

then I try to create if condtion for the list in the code:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        if(position == 0 ){
            Intent intent = new Intent (Almashaaer.this,Minaa.class);
            startActivity (intent);}
        else
        if(position == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent (Almashaaer.this,Aljamarat.class);
            startActivity (intent);
        }else.......etc
```

I try to eliminate the onClick()